Passing config variables to functions so they behave as compile time constants
In numba, I want to pass the config variable to a function as a compile-time constant. Specifically what I want to do is
    @njit
    def physics(config):
        flagA = config.flagA
        flagB = config.flagB
        aNumbaList = List()
        for i in range(100):
            if flagA:
                aNumbaList.append(i)
            else:
                aNumbaList.append(i/10)
        return aNumbaList

If the config variables are compile-time constants, this would have passed, but it is not, so it's giving me errors saying that there are two candidates
There are 2 candidate implementations:
                 - Of which 2 did not match due to:
                 ...
                 ...


I looked at one of numba meeting minutes and found that there was a way to do this Numba Meeting: 2024-03-05
I tried that, but it is still raising the same error.
Here is the code with the error message:
.. code:: ipython3

    from numba import jit, types, njit
    from numba.extending import overload
    from numba.typed import List
    import functools

.. code:: ipython3

    class Config():
        def __init__(self, flagA, flagB):
            self._flagA = flagA
            self._flagB = flagB
    
        @property
        def flagA(self):
            return self._flagA
    
        @property
        def flagB(self):
            return self._flagB

.. code:: ipython3

    @functools.cache
    def obj2strkeydict(obj, config_name):
    
        # unpack object to freevars and close over them
        tmp_a = obj.flagA
        tmp_b = obj.flagB
        assert isinstance(config_name, str)
        tmp_force_heterogeneous = config_name
    
        @njit
        def configurator():
            d = {'flagA': tmp_a,
                 'flagB': tmp_b,
                 'config_name': tmp_force_heterogeneous}
            return d
    
        # return a configuration function that returns a string-key-dict
        # representation of the configuration object.
        return configurator

.. code:: ipython3

    @njit
    def physics(cfig_func):
        config = cfig_func()
        flagA = config['flagA']
        flagB = config['flagB']
        aNumbaList = List()
        for i in range(100):
            if flagA:
                aNumbaList.append(i)
            else:
                aNumbaList.append(i/10)
        return aNumbaList

.. code:: ipython3

    def demo():
        configuration1 = Config(True, False)
        jit_config1 = obj2strkeydict(configuration1, 'config1')
        physics(jit_config1)

.. code:: ipython3

    demo()


::


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

    Cell In[83], line 1
    ----> 1 demo()


    Cell In[82], line 4, in demo()
          2 configuration1 = Config(True, False)
          3 jit_config1 = obj2strkeydict(configuration1, 'config1')
    ----> 4 physics(jit_config1)


    File ~/anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
        464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
        465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
        466         e.patch_message(msg)
    --> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
        469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
        470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
        471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')


    File ~/anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
        407     raise e
        408 else:
    --> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)


    TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
    - Resolution failure for literal arguments:
    No implementation of function Function(<function impl_append at 0x7fd87d253920>) found for signature:
    
     >>> impl_append(ListType[int64], float64)
    
    There are 2 candidate implementations:
          - Of which 2 did not match due to:
          Overload in function 'impl_append': File: numba/typed/listobject.py: Line 592.
            With argument(s): '(ListType[int64], float64)':
           Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
             TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
           No implementation of function Function(<intrinsic _cast>) found for signature:
    
            >>> _cast(float64, class(int64))
    
           There are 2 candidate implementations:
                 - Of which 2 did not match due to:
                 Intrinsic in function '_cast': File: numba/typed/typedobjectutils.py: Line 22.
                   With argument(s): '(float64, class(int64))':
                  Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
                    TypingError: cannot safely cast float64 to int64. Please cast explicitly.
             raised from /home/sam/anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/typed/typedobjectutils.py:75
           
           During: resolving callee type: Function(<intrinsic _cast>)
           During: typing of call at /home/sam/anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/typed/listobject.py (600)
           
           
           File "../anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/typed/listobject.py", line 600:
               def impl(l, item):
                   casteditem = _cast(item, itemty)
                   ^
    
      raised from /home/sam/anaconda3/envs/tardis/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numba/core/typeinfer.py:1086
    
    - Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
    None
    
    During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.containers.ListType'>, 'append') for ListType[int64])
    During: typing of call at /tmp/ipykernel_9889/739598600.py (11)
    
    
    File "../../../tmp/ipykernel_9889/739598600.py", line 11:
    <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

Any help or any reference to a related material would really help me.
Thank You.

You should create a single .py file and test with that, not with ipython (jupyter?) code fragments. If you do so, you should get an additional error message that is much more understandable.

In Numba, global variables are compile-time constant so you can use that to do what you want. Here is an example:
import numba as nb   # v0.58.1

flagA = True

@nb.njit
def physics(flagA):
    aNumbaList = nb.typed.List()
    for i in range(100):
        if flagA:
            aNumbaList.append(i)
        else:
            aNumbaList.append(i/10)
    return aNumbaList

This works well without error while passing flagA in parameter results in an error because the items in the if and else are of different types.
That being said, global variables are not great in term of software engineering, and you may want to compile the function for different configuration at runtime (e.g. based on an initialisation process, while avoiding writing in global variables).
An alternative solution is to return a function which read variable defined in a parent function so it is considered as a global one to the function and thus a compile-time constant. The variable read by the compiled function can be passed in parameter to the parent one. Here is an example:
import numba as nb

def make_physics(flagA):
    @nb.njit
    def fun():
        aNumbaList = nb.typed.List()
        for i in range(100):
            if flagA:
                aNumbaList.append(i)
            else:
                aNumbaList.append(i/10)
        return aNumbaList

    return fun

physics = make_physics(True)  # Compile a specialized function every time it is called
physics()                     # Call the compiled function generated just before

This does not results in any error too and actually works as intended. Here is the generated assembly code of the physics function showing that there is no runtime check of flagA within the main loop:
    [...]

    movq    %rax, %r12                 ; r12 = an allocated Python object (the list?)
    movq    24(%rax), %rax
    movq    %r14, (%rax)
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx                 ; i = 0
    movabsq $NRT_incref, %r13
    movabsq $numba_list_append, %rbp
    leaq    48(%rsp), %r15             ; (r15 is a pointer on i)

.LBB0_6:                               ; Main loop
    movq    %r12, %rcx                 
    callq   *%r13                      ; Call NRT_incref(r12)
    movq    %rbx, 48(%rsp)             
    movq    %r14, %rcx                 
    movq    %r15, %rdx                 
    callq   *%rbp                      ; Call numba_list_append(r14, pointer_of(i))
    testl   %eax, %eax                 
    jne .LBB0_7                        ; Stop the loop if numba_list_append returned a non-zero value
    incq    %rbx                       ; i += 1
    movq    %r12, %rcx                 
    movabsq $NRT_decref, %rax          
    callq   *%rax                      ; Call NRT_decref(r12)
    cmpq    $100, %rbx                 
    jne .LBB0_6                        ; Loop as long as i < 100

    [...]

Regarding the actual use-case, memoization and Numba function caching can help to avoid compiling the target function many times for the same configuration.

Thanks for the detailed answer, Jerome. So, I tried the global variable approach, and here is the issue with that: As long as your global variable is the same throughout the program, it works fine, but if the value is changed midway through the execution, the program will use the same global value as before and not update it. You will have to recompile it, which Numba doesn't recommend. I'll try the closure approach and get back to you.

I am considering using overload or generated_jit to return specialized functions based on the config value. Will you recommend that? Also, is there anything I should be looking out for while using them so that it doesn't affect the program's runtime?

generated_jit is AFAIK obsolete and now replaced with overload. The thing is AFAIK overload is limited to type-based overload while you seems to want overload based on values. So I think none of the two works for your use-case. Besides, generated_jit have a behaviour similar to the solution provided in the answer, except is does not always recompile the function every-time make_physics is called (I think it is similar to it once memoization is added).

I agree for global variables, but the make_physics solution is OK in this case. You can call it with different configuration and generate different functions. You can write your own CPython overload based on this. Memoization can be easily supported with @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=64) (cache up to 64 configuration -- use None for no bound at the expense of possibly many compiled functions in memory). You can also pre-compile all configurations manually when the program starts and to your own caching system (something not possible with generated_jit).

Note that the function needs to be recompiled as many time as there are configuration since you want them to be compile-time constant.

Yes. Upon looking at the codebase, generated_jit has been removed as of Numba 0.59.0. Regarding using overload, one of the ways I could make it work is by passing the config variables as Numba literals. I can use the .literal_value property. But I do think the make_physics solutions seem simple. Thank you for being so helpful.
